# How to validate mobile number or landline number using HTML 5?

Tags: html

I want validate mobile number and landline number?how to validate either mobile number nor landline number using HTML 5?
Thanks

Comment: can you include in your question an example of both a mobile number, and landline number? this can vary based on the style you want to accept when a user enters something in.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Pure code writing requests are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use attribute patterns based on what type of phone number you are looking for. In a simplified pattern you could enter the allowed characters and then the allowed length. Here the allowed numbers are from 0 to 9 and the length must be 9 characters

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{9}">
```

Here is a great link to validate if your pattern is correct. You don't want to block out a valid number.
http://html5pattern.com/Phones

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute pattern like below,

```
<input type="text" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}">
```

Comment: Thanks,but in case want to validate both landline and mobile at a time,then what is the pattern?

Comment: The pattern of mobile number and landline can be different based on the location. try to make a  regular expressions as per your need and assign in pattern attribute.